# Kubernetes Master Worker Node Kubeadm Join issue

Tags: kubernetes, installation, virtualbox

I am installing Kubernetes on Oracle Virtualbox in my laptop using Kubeadm .
Everything worked fine till i run this command on Kuberenets Worker node to join with Master node 
I got the error after running

```
sudo kubeadm join 192.168.56.100:6443 --token 0i2osm.vsp2mk63v1ypeyjf     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:18511321fcc4b622628dd1ad2f56dbdd319bf024740d58127818720828cc7bf0
```

Error

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests is not empty
        [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-kubelet.conf]: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf already exists
        [ERROR Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
        [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-pki-ca.crt]: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt already exists
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

I tried deleting files manually and ran the command again but it didnt resolve the port issue .
and whenever i stop the kubectl which is running on 10250 port and then run the command it gives error to " kubectl needs to be started and when i start the kubectl then it gives error for port 10250 is in use "

Its a kind of chicken and egg thing

Any views on how i can resolve it ?

Comment: run `kubeadm reset` on node and join again.

Answer (score 19):

you should first try

```
 #kubeadm reset
```

because you already have kubernetes it gets error.

Comment: you should delete iptabales

Comment: Didnt require to delete iptables

tried **Kubeadm reset** 
and generate new token and discovery cert and it worked 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Regarding `kubeadm reset`:

1 ) As describe [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-reset/):

```
The "reset" command executes the following phases:

preflight              Run reset pre-flight checks
update-cluster-status  Remove this node from the ClusterStatus object.
remove-etcd-member     Remove a local etcd member.
cleanup-node           Run cleanup node.
```

So I recommend to run the `preflight` phase first (by using the `--skip-phases` flag) before executing the all phases together.

2 ) When you execute the `cleanup-node` phase you can see that the following steps are being logged:

```
.
.

[reset] Stopping the kubelet service

[reset] Unmounting mounted directories in "/var/lib/kubelet"

[reset] Deleting contents of config directories: [
/etc/kubernetes/manifests 
/etc/kubernetes/pki
]

[reset] Deleting files: [
/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf 
/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf 
/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf 
/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf 
/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
]

.
.
```

Let's go over the `[reset]` entries and see how they solve the 4 errors you mentioned:

A ) The first `[reset]` entry will fix the `Port 10250 is in use` issue (kubelet was listening on this port).

B ) The fourth `[reset]` entry will fix the two errors of `/etc/kubernetes/manifests is not empty` and  `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf already exists`.

C ) And we're left with the `/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt already exists` error. 
I thought that the third `[reset]` entry of removing `/etc/kubernetes/pki` should take care of that. 
But, in my case when I ran the `kubeadm join` with verbosity level of 5 (by appending the `--v=5` flag) I encounter the error below:

```
I0929 ... checks.go:432] validating if ...
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
[ERROR FileAvailable-etc-kubernetes-pki-ca.crt]: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt already exists
```

So I had to remove the  `/etc/kubernetes/pki` folder manually and then the `kubeadm join` was successful again.

Comment: Thank you for such an detailed explanation. Is there no way to use a pre-existing kubelet config and everything else to rejoin a node back to it's master? Or do we need to always use kubeadm reset to join it anywhere for that matter?

Answer (score 4):

Do not run

```
kubeadm init (do not do this)
```

on a worker node before joining.  This is only run on your primary node.  Doing this can be why you already have these files, when you should not. As Yasin, said:

```
kubeadm reset
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer to this problem.